# Data Annotation Ranges of Dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, model-view-controller, data-annotations

Is it possible to use `[Range]` annotation for dates?

something like

```
[Range(typeof(DateTime), DateTime.MinValue.ToString(), DateTime.Today.ToString())]
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[Docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx) says you can use the RangeAttribute

```
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/2/2004", "3/4/2004",
        ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
public datetime Something { get; set;}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan - I get an error though and not sure how to fix:

'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RangeAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments

any idea?

Comment: Thanks for all your help Dan - That seems to work but I can't substitue theh hardcodes strings for something like DateTime.Now.Date.toString() I get:

An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Sry - I'm probably doing something dumb :)

Davy

Comment: I am having trouble getting this method to work implicitly with jquery.validate. I get the impression that the range validation doesn't really translate to it?

Comment: I have tried doing this: but it doesn't seem to work: any ideas why? [Range(typeof(DateTime),DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString(), "3/4/2022", ErrorMessage = "Error message here")], I want to validate if the date is choose is less then today's date... thx!

Comment: Ben ... unfortunately in a decorating attribute the values you use must be static and not dynamic. I'd suggest writing your own DataAnnotation if you need it to be dynamic.

Comment: That MSDN documentation is incorrect if you are using a UK date format - I have an open question on this issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251834/data-annotation-ranges-of-uk-datetime-fields

Comment: They got it so wrong. They should have restrict the min and max date format to invariant culture.

Answer (score 83):

I did this to fix your problem

```
 public class DateAttribute : RangeAttribute
   {
      public DateAttribute()
        : base(typeof(DateTime), DateTime.Now.AddYears(-20).ToShortDateString(),     DateTime.Now.AddYears(2).ToShortDateString()) { } 
   }
```

Comment: Just come across this, and am amazed at how simple but effective it is! Can't believe it has so few votes.

Comment: How do you use this? An example please?

Comment: If your class name is MyDateAttribute, simply put [MyDate] above the property you want to restrict.

Comment: can we make this dynamic ?? For example , [CustomDateRange(startDate=DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now.AddDays(5))]

Comment: @BimalDas No. The ctors for the attribute must take compile time constants, but maybe you can try DI'ing the required values into the parameterless ctor for `MyDateAttribute`.

Comment: Sorry, @BimalDas, I meant DI container resolving the required values in the parameterless ctor.

Comment: Shame that this isn't at the top of the page. Stack Overflow definitely lacks something.

Answer (score 9):

jQuery validation does not work with `[Range(typeof(DateTime),"date1","date2"]` --
My MSDN doc is incorrect.

Comment: ALthough you can make it work by configuring the `$.validator` - [MVC model validation for date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777412/mvc-model-validation-for-date/42036626#42036626)

Answer (score 6):

Here is another solution.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date Of Birth is Required")]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage ="Invalid Date Format")]
[Remote("IsValidDateOfBirth", "Validation", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Please provide a valid date of birth.")]
[Display(Name ="Date of Birth")]
public DateTime DOB{ get; set; }
```

The simply create a new MVC controller called ValidationController and past this code in there. The nice thing about the "Remote" approach is you can leverage this framework to handle any kind of validations based on your custom logic.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace YOURNAMESPACEHERE
{
    public class ValidationController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult IsValidDateOfBirth(string dob)
        {
            var min = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-21);
            var max = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-110);
            var msg = string.Format("Please enter a value between {0:MM/dd/yyyy} and {1:MM/dd/yyyy}", max,min );
            try
            {
                var date = DateTime.Parse(dob);
                if(date > min || date < max)
                    return Json(msg);
                else
                    return Json(true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Json(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this approach but as a GET request. You can implement it globally using the Request.QueryString[0] as the dob parameter instead of a strongly typed model. Discovered this to be more suitable to my project because I'm using complex models and I don't like dependency on the correct case/spelling of parameters.

Answer (score 5):

For those rare occurrences when you are forced to write a date as a string (when using attributes), I highly recommend using the [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) notation. 
That eliminates any confusion as to whether 01/02/2004 is january 2nd or february 1st.

```
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "2004-12-01", "2004-12-31",
    ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
public datetime Something { get; set;}
```

Comment: I could not get this to work for love nor money. I think it's possibly something to do with the date formats being entered by users and the date formats so I used [Remote] annotation for a custom controller to solve.

Answer (score 3):

I use this approach:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
internal sealed class DateRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public DateTime Minimum { get; }
    public DateTime Maximum { get; }

    public DateRangeAttribute(string minimum = null, string maximum = null, string format = null)
    {
        format = format ?? @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFFK"; //iso8601

        Minimum = minimum == null ? DateTime.MinValue : DateTime.ParseExact(minimum, new[] { format }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None); //0 invariantculture
        Maximum = maximum == null ? DateTime.MaxValue : DateTime.ParseExact(maximum, new[] { format }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None); //0 invariantculture

        if (Minimum > Maximum)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Specified max-date '{maximum}' is less than the specified min-date '{minimum}'");
    }
    //0 the sole reason for employing this custom validator instead of the mere rangevalidator is that we wanted to apply invariantculture to the parsing instead of
    //  using currentculture like the range attribute does    this is immensely important in order for us to be able to dodge nasty hiccups in production environments

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) //0 null
            return true;

        var s = value as string;
        if (s != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) //0 null
            return true;

        var min = (IComparable)Minimum;
        var max = (IComparable)Maximum;
        return min.CompareTo(value) <= 0 && max.CompareTo(value) >= 0;
    }
    //0 null values should be handled with the required attribute

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name) => string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ErrorMessageString, name, Minimum, Maximum);
}
```

And use it like so:

```
[DateRange("2004-12-01", "2004-12-2", "yyyy-M-d")]
ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found issues with the `[Range(typeof(DateTime)]` annotation and would describe it as "clunky at best" it leaves too much to chance IF it works.

Remote validation seems to be a good way of: avoiding javascript in views and maintaining server side code integrity, personally never like sending code to a client to execute if I can avoid it.

Using @StackThis answer as a base and reference to an [article](http://www.aaronstannard.com/remote-validation-asp-net-mvc3/) on remote validation in MVC3

**Model**

```
public class SomeDateModel
{
    public int MinYears = 18;
    public int MaxYears = 110;

    [Display(Name = "Date of birth", Prompt = "e.g. 01/01/1900")]
    [Remote(action: "ValidateDateBetweenYearsFromNow", controller: "Validation", areaReference: AreaReference.UseRoot, AdditionalFields = "MinYears,MaxYears", HttpMethod = "GET" ,ErrorMessage = "Subject must be over 18")]
    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller - Deployed at the root directory**

```
namespace Controllers
{
    public class ValidationController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("ValidateDateBetweenYearsFromNow")]
        public JsonResult ValidateDateBetweenYearsFromNow_Get()
        {
            //This method expects 3 parameters, they're anonymously declared through the Request Querystring,
            //Ensure the order of params is:
            //[0] DateTime
            //[1] Int Minmum Years Ago e.g. for 18 years from today this would be 18
            //[2] int Maximum Years Ago e.g. for 100 years from today this would be 100
            var msg = string.Format("An error occured checking the Date field validity");
            try
            {
                int MinYears = int.Parse(Request.QueryString[1]);
                int MaxYears = int.Parse(Request.QueryString[2]);

                //Use (0 - x) to invert the positive int to a negative.
                var min = DateTime.Now.AddYears((0-MinYears));
                var max = DateTime.Now.AddYears((0-MaxYears));

                //reset the response error msg now all parsing and assignmenst succeeded.
                msg = string.Format("Please enter a value between {0:dd/MM/yyyy} and {1:dd/MM/yyyy}", max, min);
                var date = DateTime.Parse(Request.QueryString[0]);
                if (date > min || date < max)
                    //switch the return value here from "msg" to "false" as a bool to use the MODEL error message
                    return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                else
                    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `msg` variable is displayed as part of the Html helper ValidationSummary or the Html helper ValidationFor(x=>x.DATETIME)

**View**

It's important to note that the fields passed as parameter 2 and 3 must exist in the view  in order for the remote validation to pass the values to the controller:

```
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DOB)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MinYears)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MaxYears)
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
```

The model and Html helpers will do all the jquery work for you.