# How to disable past date in Editorfor?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

My model is

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Effective Date")]
public DateTime EFFECTIVEDATE;
```

I am using Razor in View

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EFFECTIVEDATE)
```

How can I enforce MinDate (like from Jquery Datepicker) to disable previous dates in dropdown calendar using Annotations?

Comment: You can create your own Attribute - for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844747/restrict-datetime-value-with-data-annotations

Comment: @JamesP Thank you.. I was just curious if visual studio supported any annotation to restrict range