# Set Maximum DateTime on a field in MVC application via DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, model-view-controller, data-annotations

I need to find the best way to limit my DateTime field to today's date. I need to make sure that users do not select a date in the future and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do it in my C# MVC application.

I could and I will do it on a client side via Javascript.
What I'm trying to figure out is the best way to do it on the server side, via DataAnnotations possibly ?

Is there a DataAnnotations attribute I can use to specify max DateTime ? Or is it not a good way to do it through dataannotations because every day my MaxDate will change to its current day ?

Should I do validation just via C# programming logic ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406046/data-annotation-ranges-of-dates

Comment: It's not. My question is not about static dates.
I'm aware of Range dataAnnotations attribute but I'm concerned using DateTime.Now in that attribute is not a good idea.
Or is it ok ?
Is this acceptable ?

[Range(typeof(DateTime), DateTime.Min, DateTime.Now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got something similar in one of my apps

```
 public sealed class DateEndAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string DateStartProperty { get; set; }
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // Get Value of the Date property
        string dateString = HttpContext.Current.Request[YourDateProperty];
        DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now
        DateTime dateProperty = DateTime.Parse(dateString);

        // 
        return dateProperty < dateNow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question on custom dataAnnotations as I haven't worked with them before. Would it be a good practice to stick the custom validator inside of the Entity model class or should it be kept separately ?

Comment: I usually store all my custom attributes separately, unless the are specific to that class only.

Comment: Thank you. I combined yours and the following solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390403/datetime-date-and-hour-validation-with-data-annotation

Comment: MrBliz, when you get the property, why not use the passed in `value` instead of inspecting the current request for a named property value. That way the attribute could be re-used easily across different properties.

Comment: you need to ensure you take into consideration the culture settings otherwise your DateTime parse will throw an exception if it cannot parse to the correct format passed into the Request.