# Is there a RangeAttribute for DateTime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Datetime field in my Model and need to validate it so that when it is created it has to fall between **Now** and **6 Years Prior**. I have tried using range like

```
[Range(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-6), DateTime.Now)]
public DateTime Datetim { get; set; }
```

But this throws an error cannot convert system datetime to double. Can anyone suggest a workaround to this in the model itself?

Comment: For anyone using **ASP MVC**, trying client-side validation with `RangeAttribute` for datetime validation you might wanna see this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777412/mvc-model-va%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Blidation-for-date).

Comment: what about asp.net webapi ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use this attribute:

```
public class CustomDateAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
  public CustomDateAttribute()
    : base(typeof(DateTime), 
            DateTime.Now.AddYears(-6).ToShortDateString(),
            DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()) 
  { } 
}
```

Comment: To get more beautiful validation message FormatErrorMessage method should be overriden

Comment: I know this is old, but how do you use this in the model?

Comment: You add it as an attribute(with the code above you would just type [CustomDate] above the property).

Comment: Note that ToShortDateString() only includes the Date portion of the DateTime, if you're looking to validate up to now (the second), toString might be better. But also note that this doesn't account for local vs UTC time at all, since it does a comparison to the output of ToString which strips whether it's local or UTC.

Answer (score 36):

Even though there is an overload for `Range` attribute that accepts type and boundary values of that type and allows something like this:

```
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/2011", "1/1/2012", ErrorMessage="Date is out of Range")]
```

what you are trying to achieve is not possible using this attribute. The problem is that attributes accept only constants as parameters. Obviously neither `DateTime.Now` nor `DateTime.Now.AddYears(-6)` are constants.

However you can still do this creating your own validation attribute:

```
public class DateTimeRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    //implementation
}
```

Comment: This use of `Range`, even under normal usage as your example, doesn't work. It always invalidates even if the value is in the range

Comment: Worked fine for me

Comment: For me too! Best anwser!

Comment: @toddmo and other seekers.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15418#issuecomment-547099928
If I understood correctly, client-side validation is not done yet.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery validation does not work with `RangeAttribute`, [per Rick Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16990751). This renders the selected solution incorrect if you're using ASP.NET MVC 5's built-in jQuery validation.

Instead, see the below code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27184482/) answer.

```
public class WithinSixYearsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        value = (DateTime)value;
        // This assumes inclusivity, i.e. exactly six years ago is okay
        if (DateTime.Now.AddYears(-6).CompareTo(value) <= 0 && DateTime.Now.CompareTo(value) >= 0)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Date must be within the last six years!");
        }
    }
}
```

And it's implemented like any other attribute.

```
[WithinSixYears]
public DateTime SixYearDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: The jQuery validation can be easily extended to support date ranges. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42036626/642287