# Regular expression validation time

Tags: regex, validation, time, asp.net-mvc-5

I want do validation time(format `HH:MM`) using regular expression. I have :

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[RegularExpression(@"^(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$", ErrorMessage = "Time format HH:MM ")]
public System.DateTime Time { get; set; }
```

And when I add time in textbox in form dynamic validation (side client) is ok. When i write example `43:444` it is select. When I write example `12:43` is ok (does not detect the error) but when I click submit, ErrorMessage was showed, although format is ok. How i can repair it?

Comment: Is there really no chance to map that attribute to some bit of code that uses `DateTime.TryParseExact`? Xcheck [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182606/asp-mvc-5-client-validation-for-range-of-datetimes).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/zE3uI5/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using this custom validation:

```
[ValidateDate]
public string Time { get; set; }
       ^^^^^^
```

Here is the implementation of the `ValidateDate` attribute:

```
public class ValidateDate: ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {                 
        DateTime dateValue;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "HH:mm", 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        else
            return new ValidationResult("Expected time format: HH:mm.");
    }
}
```

Note that if you plan to also accept `2:00`-like values, you need to use `new[] {"HH:mm", "H:mm"}` instead of `"HH:mm"`.

Comment: I get exception in the condition:

 "An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in RadioSite.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'."

Comment: I think you can fix it by adding `DateTime dt_value = (DateTime)value;` and replacing `(string)value` with `string.Format("{0}:{1}", dt_value.Hour, dt_value.Minute)`.

Comment: This work probably ok. Thank you!. But i I have one more question: when I  enter example: 21:22:22 (with seconds) this validation is success. How do that time with seconds will be incorrect?

Comment: Then you need to change the property type to string, otherwise it looks meaningless. I updated the answer. I even think you can use acregex now, but I still believe that date and time validation should be done without regex. It is easier to maintain and scale with appropriate methods and classes.