# Client side validation: Permit only old date from calender

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I allow users to only enter an old date if I have this code in model, before the `BirthDate` property?

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public System.DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Can this be achieved without using JavaScript? If yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean by old date?

Comment: you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321948/is-there-a-rangeattribute-for-datetime

Comment: Do you mean if you have a property birthday and user enters a date i.e 11/12/1995. If user wants to edit the birthday they can enter any date less than 11/12/1995 i.e 10/12/1994?

Comment: Use a conditional validation attribute such as a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[LessThan]` attribute (or write your own)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I wrote a custom validator for this one. However, user can still view a future date, i.e. calendar still shows future date. Is there a way to limit calendar to display dates between those specified range?

Comment: If your using a jquery datepicker plugin it will have options for setting the max date. If you using the browsers HTML-5 datepicker (which is only supported in Chrome and Edge), then you can use the `max="2016-10-14"` attribute

Answer (score 0):

You should extend the `RangeAttribute` to decorate `DateTime` models field.

You may for example create a new validation attribute: `BirthDateAttribute`

```
public class BirthDateAttribute : RangeAttribute {

   public BirthDateAttribute() 
                   : base(
                           typeof(DateTime), 
                           DateTime.Now.AddYears(-120).ToShortDateString(), 
                           DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)ToShortDateString()
                     ) { } 
}
```

And then, you can apply it to decorate your DateTime property:

```
[BirthDateAttribute]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public System.DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Where do I write this custom validator if i am using MVC with EF?

Comment: Everywhere, but I suggest you to write in the model folder a sub folder ValidationExtension and there add a class file BirthDateAttribute.cs.. using the same   namespace of your model. Then decorate your model with the new attribute