# Custom Date Range Validation not removing Time after .NET 5 migration

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations, .net-5

This custom Validator that I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2907678/12143342) is not working after migrating our project to .NET 5. It is not removing the time part of the date.

```
public class DateAttribute : RangeAttribute
    {
        public DateAttribute(int min, int max)
          : base(typeof(DateTime), DateTime.Now.AddYears(min).ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.AddYears(max).Date.ToShortDateString()) { }
    }
```

```
[Required, DisplayName("Date")]
[Date(-2, 0, ErrorMessage = "The Date should be within the last two years.")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

This is what the html input looks like upon inspecting it:

```
<input type="date" value="2000-05-07" data-val="true" data-val-range="The Date should be within the last two years." data-val-range-max="04/12/2021 00:00:00" data-val-range-min="04/12/2019 00:00:00" data-val-required="The Date field is required." id="Date" name="Date">
```

I have tried using ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), ToString("d"), and hardcoding the min and max inside the AddYears() methods, but the same thing happens.

It was working fine before on .NET Core 3.1, which we were using until 4 days ago. That's the only thing I can think of that was changed.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a timezone issue. Is the time a consistent value when it shows up? For instance, when I ran into this issue the time always said 5AM because it converts from my timezone to UTC (or the other way around).

Comment: Hi, time is always 00:00:00 in the data-range attribute values

Comment: Sometimes the time zone issue occurs between the client and server. JS adds the time zone to the date and c# tries to convert it to UTC when converting from JS which changes the time. Is the time value present when you get Date in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to display only date in the generated `data-val-range-max` and `data-val-range-min`, you need change your customed RangeAttribute like below:

```
public class DateAttribute : RangeAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public DateAttribute(int min, int max)
      : base(typeof(DateTime), DateTime.Now.AddYears(min).ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.AddYears(max).Date.ToShortDateString()) 
    {
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
    }
    
    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-range-max", DateTime.Now.AddYears(Max).ToShortDateString());
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-range-min", DateTime.Now.AddYears(Min).Date.ToShortDateString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having to write a jQuery script? It is working fine as it is, it's just that the time isn't removed so any value that is input automatically fails

Comment: What do you mean? Actually in my code I do not write any jQuery script.

Comment: I am new, my apologies. What is the AddValidation method doing? It doesn't seem like it is being called...

Comment: Hi @Trevor, Any update? Did my answer help you resolve your issue?